# Как правильно настроить webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Пытаюсь настроить webpack-dev-server, возникла проблема.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: [
            "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080",
            "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
            "./src/Scripts/Index/View"
        ]
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: "/",
        path: __dirname + "/public/",
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "index.html",
            template: "./src/Views/Index.ejs"
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            _: "underscore"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loaders: ["react-hot", "babel"]
        }, {
            test: /\.ejs$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: "ejs"
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "html"
        }]
    },
    ejsLoader: {
        reactOutput: "hello"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./public",
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};
```

**Index.ejs**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"><%= reactOutput %></div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Запускаю команду `webpack-dev-server` захожу на http://localhost:8080/ выдает ошибку

> Html Webpack Plugin:   ReferenceError: reactOutput is not defined
>
> - Index.ejs:554 module.exports
>     E:/JS/universal-test/src/Views/Index.ejs:
>     554:12
> - index.js:255 
>     [universal-test]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:255:16
> - util.js:16 tryCatcher
>     [universal-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
> - promise.js:504 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>     [universal-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:504:31
> - promise.js:561 Promise._settlePromise
>     [universal-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:561:18
> - promise.js:598 Promise._settlePromiseCtx
>     [universal-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:598:10
> - async.js:143 Async._drainQueue
>     [universal-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:143:12
> - async.js:148 Async._drainQueues
>     [universal-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:148:10
> - async.js:17 Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate]
>     [universal-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:17:14

что не так в моем конфиге?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070303/uncaught-referenceerror-react-is-not-defined

Comment: посомтрите здесь https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/262